# Websockets private messages/rooms

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to make chat in my website ,but to use websockets I have to upgrade to VDS server(I have to pay more for that). Shortly could you help me whether my idea would work, i want to implement private chat for only two users, for example I have 4 users, websocket for user 1 and 2 will be wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=1
And for user 3 and 4 url will be
wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=2 .
So basically if I send smth to chat with id 1, chat with id 2 won't recieve that message as I want? Or different GET params will be treated as one websocket, not two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to have a data-broker that talks to the HTTP/S server and lets it know endpoints.

To elaborate!

Your chat-server would have a WSS Server, and a broker client (to send incoming data out)
The data-broker will receive all connections/messages and route them back and forth, so say

User#1 on WSS1.yoursite.com:4020 sent a message to User#10109 at WSS209.yoursite.com:2945, the broker will middle-man and direct to whom it concerns whether it's a global or private message.

### How you differentiate the users is through a session carried via the socket. You'd set a unique handle (identifier) that counts up indefinitely and so there could never be duplicate users or someone sniffing another persons message.

Setup is a bit savage, but if you want simple just run a unique handle per connection and map the socket so anytime you need to; you call the map if a match exists, send the message.

Comment: User 1 and 2 will have the same chat id, that is like their room where they have same chat id, my question is wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=1 and wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=2 will be like separate channels? Or it will be one channel.If they are separate when I send to channel with id1 only chat channel with id1 would recieve that

Comment: You should probably call 'id' -> 'room'. If a user joins a room, their mapped to that room specifically their messages will never leave that zone unless you intend on it in the design. With what I've explain you can set it up where a WSS can be on different ports/room and still manage to deliver the message to the right person or room.

Comment: Map/Array each connection and sort it so you can do this with ease!

Comment: I am novice at websockets, so I try to explain easier, like if I create a wss://mywebsite/profile and for example wss://mywebsite/mainpage, that will be different sockets BUT would sockets like chat?id=1 and chat?id=2 will be different sockets as like profile and mainpage (that is just examples)

Comment: It'd likely depending on your load-balancing solution submit to one IP through proxied DNS or however you got it setup and reference the parameter passed through. So in your case say 1.1.1.1 was the IP; 1.1.1.1?id=1 and 1.1.1.1?id=0

Answer (score 1):

With one pair chat between 1 and 2, your server has to open 2 sockets. 1 socket for chat between 1 and the server, the other socket for chat between 2 and the server.

As a beginning of one user connect to the server, you have to create a websocket for that user (if you want all user always ready for chatting). And now you have a set of websocket according to the id of users. Whenever some one send a chat over a socket along with an receiver's id, you now find out which socket to send to, with that receiver, and send the chat to receiver's socket. In most cases, you may want to send the chat back to the sender too.

Edit: dont worry about private chats, as a websocket created between one user and a server, a message from server to that socket can only be sent to the socket's user

Comment: That's not really answering my question, user 1 and user 2 would have the same chat id for example 1 (it is not based on their id ). So user 1 and user 2 both connected to wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=1 , and will it be separate websocket from wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=2, or not, so when I send something to chat id 1 it will be in chat id 1 and chat id 2 can't recieve that? Or I amisunderstood

Comment: websocket is not like an api, so your `wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=2` is just like an api for the server to create a room chat. As I understand what you want is when user 3 access `wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=2`, your server creates a socket with user 3 and wait for another user to join the room. When a socket connection is established, user 3 doesnot need that link `wss://mywebsite.com:8080/chat.php?id=2` to chat